# How to get element defined under MenuItem.Template from code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

I want to get the "textBoxLatitde" control in code behind.

```
<Image Name="icon">
 <ContextMenu>
      <MenuItem>
           <MenuItem.Template>
             <ControlTemplate>
              <Grid>
               <TextBlock Name="placeHolderText" Text="Lat :"/>
               <TextBox  Name="textBoxLatitde" />                    
              </Grid>
             </ControlTemplate>
          </MenuItem.Template>
     </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

Comment: You can get the templete object from some control. But I c

Comment: But I do not recomend. Because it is so difficult and dirty. If you can add some UI event into the Grid, you can cast the sender control as concrete type. And you can also get the siblings controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Grid grid = (icon.ContextMenu.Items[0] as MenuItem).Template.LoadContent() as Grid;
TextBox textBox = grid.Children[1] as TextBox;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to access the `ContextMenu` templates just after it is loaded.
So add this code in the constructor of your `Window`:

```
icon.ContextMenu.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(ContextMenuLoaded);
```

Then add this method to the same `Window`:

```
private void ContextMenuLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ContextMenu contextMenu = sender as ContextMenu;
    MenuItem menuItem = contextMenu.Items[0] as MenuItem;
    TextBox textBox = menuItem.Template.FindName("textBoxLatitde", menuItem) as TextBox;

    textBox.Text = "Some text";
}
```

Just remember that a `ContextMenu` is loaded and unloaded each time that you open/close it.